# Dynamic ChartJS

Tags: javascript, java, charts

I have recently discovered chartJS and adore the design. Now I am struggling to get the data dynamic.

My goal is to retrieve data from the postgresDB in my Java Controller and route it to the javascript file to display it in the jsp files. But I don't know how to access the data in the java files out of the javascripts.

Thank you for your time and helping me!
Yours, Janick

Edit:
In the controller I've tried to put a JSON Object as String in the request:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("20210701",100.00);
        json.addProperty("20210702",101.00);
        json.addProperty("20210703",102.00);
        String strJson = json.toString();
        request.setAttribute("json",strJson);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

and in the Javascript file:

```
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
console.log(params);
```

Comment: Javascript runs on the client side. You need to insert that data from your jsp when generating the page response. Can you provide some code you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi I've updated the original post with my code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know how to do this with Java? But in .NET with ASP you can use Ajax or PageMethods to call a server-side web service or web method and query the database and then use Chart.js dynamically. You can of course control the web service with parameters and in the return object you can write arrays or lists for the result and then use a callback method to make the chart dynamic.